# Regex: how to match patterns that have " ' " for exact three times?

Tags: regex

I wanna match patterns like: `'''abc'''`. But there are some noise like `''''''abc'''` in the document. I just want the words which are preceded by exact three `" ' "`. I tried `" [^']'''[^'] "`. But it does not work. Regular expression `" '{3} "` will match more than three `" ' "`.

So can anybody help me?

Comment: Is there some kind of delimiter? If the patterns are separated by a space, you can check to make sure there is a space in front of it

Comment: `"'{3}"` will not match more than 3 `'`. It will match exactly 3 `'`. It is different from `"'{3,}"`

Comment: `I just want the words which are preceded by exact three " ' "` Are you sure that's what you want? If you have `'''abc def'''` what should it match? Just `abc` or `abc def`? What if you have  `'''abc def'''ghi`? Should it also return `ghi`? Please include some examples in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically already gave the solution yourself. If you want to match strings which are surrounded by exactly 3 `'`, then do this (I use Python for my examples):

```
In [33]: re.findall("'{3}\w+'{3}", "'''abc'''")
Out[33]: ["'''abc'''"]
```

If you want avoid those strings that are preceded by more than 3 `'`, then you best take a negative look-behind assertion `(?<!...)`:

```
In [59]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}", "'''abc'''")
Out[59]: ["'''abc'''"]

In [60]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}", "''''''''''abc'''")
Out[60]: []

In [62]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}", "'''abc''''''''''")
Out[62]: ["'''abc'''"]
```

If you also want to avoid strings that are succeeded by more than 3 `'`, add a negative look-ahead assertion `(?!...)`:

```
In [63]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}(?!')", "'''abc'''")
Out[63]: ["'''abc'''"]

In [64]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}(?!')", "''''''''''abc'''")
Out[64]: []

In [65]: re.findall("(?<!')'{3}\w+'{3}(?!')", "'''abc''''''''''")
Out[65]: []
```

**Note:** It depends on your programming language whether look-ahead and look-behind are supported. If so, this is the best way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks. But what about " ''''''abc''' "? I don't want such pattern. But your solution can match it as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<!')'{3}(?!')
```

use negative lookahead (and lookbehind), if supported.

Edit: assuming you want to match `'''` from `'''abc'''`, because that is what your question implies. If different, please specify.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `^[^']*'{3}[^']+'{3}[^']*$`.  Note the `[^']+` in the middle, because you also need to tell it that there is something between the three ''' on either side.

Comment: I revised to account for situation where '''abc''' might be at the very end of a line.

Comment: Also revised with beginning '*' after first character class to make it work at the beginning of the line.  All of this shows that negative look aheads are a good idea, @TDaver